# How to source file in bash with Robot framework?

Tags: bash, environment-variables, robotframework

Anyone know how to source a file using Robot framework?

I try to use "Run" or "Run Process" to execute source, but seems the environment variables set in the sourced file are not retained.

e.g.

```
${out} | Run Process | source | set_config.sh | shell=True
${out} | Run Process | check_env_vars.pl
```

The check_env_vars.pl returns the error message saying the environment vars are not set yet, although they have been set in the previous line.
Any suggestion on how to accomplish this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: is the question about executing a shell script from robot? or you mean you are trying to set environment variables but it is not set?

Comment: yes, it's about how to retain the env values set in the shell script so they can be used by other program afterwards (e.g. perl script).

Answer (score 3):

Set environmental variables using "Set Environment Variable" instead and I see it accessible throughout the robot test run.

```
*** Settings ***
Library  Process
Library  OperatingSystem

*** Test Cases ***
sample
    Set Environment Variable  VAR  2
    Run Process   sh  Sample2.sh
```

Sample.sh looks like:

```
echo $VAR > console.txt
```

The env variable which is set in robotframework, is accessible in Sample2.sh also. In the same way you can set variables are run "check_env_vars.pl" which will have access to all those variables.

Hope it helps!